# IE9 miscalculates min-height on DOM update with overflow set

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I've run into what seems like a very specific bug in IE9 layout rendering, where the height of a div with `box-sizing: border-box` and a `min-height` is calculated incorrectly when the inner content is resized.

Given the following markup and CSS:

```html
<div class="constrained">
    <div class="content">Content</div>
</div>
```

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
.constrained {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    min-height: 300px;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

The `div.constrained` renders appropriately at 300px height (278px inner height) when the page loads. When new content is injected into `div.content` via JavaScript, the `div.constrained` container grows to 322px height, as if the box-sizing were no longer applied.

JSFiddle demonstration:
http://jsfiddle.net/eafztwb2/16/

This only occurs with overflow values of `auto`, `visible` or `scroll`. Setting the `overflow-x` to `hidden`, or `inherit` (so long as inherit doesn't end up evaluating to one of the former) does not show the problem.

This isn't a question so much as knowledge-sharing, but I'd be interested in solutions that work around this while still allowing `overflow-x: auto`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This definitely does look like a layout bug, but fortunately the work-around is pretty simple. Apply a `height` to your element, along with the `min-height`. For example:

```css
.constrained {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 300px;
}
```

The issue exists in Internet Explorer 10 as well. This solution works for both IE 9 and 10. Internet Explorer 11 appears to have resolved this on its own - I was unable to repro the issue there.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eafztwb2/23/

Comment: That does solve the incorrect resize, but it introduces another problem that the constrained div doesn't grow when more content is added.

Comment: @timbonicus Sorry, `0` wasn't a good value to use. Using `100%` instead will yield better results.